# sqlplus list object name and size in kb of each object in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list all the objects names and size in kb of each objects in the a schema(e.g book) but I have no idea how to do it. any good reference that I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

The `DBA_OBJECTS` data dictionary view holds information about all the objects in the database. `DBA_SEGMENTS` holds information on segments (e.g. tables, indexes, materialized views, etc. See the full details in [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c03block.htm)). Objects which are not backed by segments are just definitions stored in Oracle's internal tables (e.g. a view is no more than a couple of bytes of data its text takes), so they can probably safely be neglected.

Once we've established that, it's a simple matter of outer joining the two tables:

```
SELECT          object_name, object_type, bytes/1024 AS KB
FROM            dba_objects do
LEFT OUTER JOIN dba_segments ds on do.object_name = ds.segment_name
WHERE           do.owner = 'BOOK'
```

Note that unfortunately, there's no `ALL_SEGMENTS` variant of that table, so you'll have to use a user with permissions on the `DBA_*` views. Alternatively, you could log in with the user you want to retrieve data for and use the `USER_*` variant:

```
SELECT          object_name, object_type, bytes/1024 AS KB
FROM            user_objects uo
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_segments us on uo.object_name = us.segment_name
```

Comment: X/1024/1024 gives MiByte, not K!

Comment: @Wernfried Good catch, thanks! Don't know what came over me... Fixed.